# Flutter- Creating multiple scaffold containers with if statement

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart, containers

I would like to create several containers in a scaffold.

Do I have to create them manually or can I reduce the code by using an if with counter statement to generate them?

If I can use an if statement could you provide a simple example?

Thanks.

Comment: The real question is WHYYY. I would advise you to go through some tutorials or courses that explain how widget tree works

Comment: although you asked a valid question, please add some context or scenario

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty vague. It really depends on what you need. But yes, you can use `if()` and even `for()` in the widget tree. Here is an example for each of them :

```
// State variable
var list = ["first", "second"];

// in build() method
if(list.isNotEmpty)
  Container()

Column(children: [
  for(var item in list)
    Container(child: Text(item))
])
```